# Почему не работает программа, если в подключаемом файле две строки?

Tags: синтаксический-анализ, powershell

Всем доброго вечера!

Возник вопрос в проге. Если в подключаемом файле одна строка, все работает, но если их 2 и более, то прога уже ложится. Ошибку выдает в `splite`, я так понимаю, что надо заменять enter пробел. Может, кто подскажет, как это сделать? Заранее спасибо!

```
$number_a = Read-Host "Enter a "; 
$number_b = Read-Host "Enter b ";
$sum = 0;
$razn = 0; 
$string = Get-Content d:\учёба\СПО\SPO_lab1\input.txt;
$array = $string.split(" ");
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $array.length; $i++){

    if ([int]$array[$i] -le $number_a ) {
        $razn = $number_a - [int]$array[$i];
    }
    else {
        $razn = $array[$i] - $number_a;
    }
    if ($razn -le $number_b) {
        $sum = $sum + $razn
    }
    $razn = 0; 
}

$file = 'd:\учёба\СПО\SPO_lab1\res.txt'
$issetFile = Test-Path $file;
if ($issetFile){
    $sum | Out-File $file -Force;
    echo "Done! Result is $sum";
}else{
    echo 'File not found`n. File res.txt is created!';
    New-Item -Path $file -ItemType "file";
    $sum | Out-File $file -Force;
    echo "Done! Result is $sum";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой метод — разбивать по пробелам **и** концам строк.

Для этого передайте несколько аргументов в `split`.

```
$array = $string.split(' `n');
```

По поводу того, *почему* программа не работала: у вас, как вы правильно заметили в вопросе, не было разбиения по концам строк, и некоторые элементы в  `$array` содержали посередине конец строки! При этом попытка преобразовать в число (`[int]$array[$i]`) приводила к падению.